# Magento 1.9.1 Not sending order emails

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, sales-order

Magento will not send order emails automatically or manually. The invoice emails work(only manually), but when something is ordered the order doesn't get send to the customer's email address.

If I go into the backend and send it manually it still doesn't go.

Oddly, on the front end as a customer you can manually view your order for printing so it is definitely creating the order document from the template.

Sales email settings have been set up, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Is your Magento cronjob running? Since 1.9.1 the order e-mails are scheduled to be send thru the cron instead of directly.

Comment: @VladimirKerkhoff is 100% correct, in Magento 1.9.1 emails are sent via cron http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes

Comment: OK I am so lost here now, thanks for your help anyway, I will Google some more. I am just shocked that it doesnt send order emails to admin and user out of the box.

Comment: Check http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job on how to enable the cronjob for your installation.

Comment: *"I am just shocked that it doesnt send order emails to admin and user out of the box."* But, it *does* - using a scheduled job. Setting up the server to execute the scheduled job script via cron is necessary for a Magento store to function - always has been.

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.9.1 the order e-mails are scheduled to be send thru the cron instead of directly. To enable cron for your Magento installation check: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: Ok, this is way beyond me...
It is a stock installation, I find it hard to believe that cron needs modifying from stock to send an order email when someone buys something from a web store...

Anyway I have installed lanot extension which shows the cron jobs
core_email_queue_send_all */1 * * * * core/email_queue::send

and in system>config>system>cron Generate Schedules Every 15 minutes

With regards to the replies, I will get someone to look into it for me following the links you have sent.

Thank you

Comment: Not that I am doubting anything here, you guys have been a great help in getting back so quick, but it just seems a be backwards for Magento to go this way. Looking at related posts it looks like 1.9.1 and sending emails is proving to be an issue for most users.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, turns out cron for magento was fine out of the box and doesnt need modding. It was that the server wasn't running www.mysite.com/cron.php

Fix here: http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob